# Can friends see how many people are in my party?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can people on your friend's list see how many people you are currently partied with?

Mainly wondering if they can tell when a game is full or when there is an open slot (not that I would ever avoid any of my wonderful under leveled/geared friends).

What about in a game versus while waiting in the menus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in menus, if you are on their friends list, they will have an option to "Quick Join" you. If they mouse over your name in that list, they will see who you are playing, what quest, and who you are partied with (but not their names, just portraits).

In game, using just the friends list, they don't get this extended amount of info, however they will still see who you are playing as (name and class), what quest, and how many people.

Another interesting thing to note, if they are in a game, they cannot "quick join" you, they would have to be invited by you. However, they could leave their game and then quick join without an invitation.

This is all assuming you have the quick join feature enabled. If you do not, they will not have anything to mouse over and see if there are empty slots in your game. You would have to manually invite them at that point.

Comment: Does it show them the actual player names of who I am playing with? And I'm assuming turning the quick join feature off would remove the ability for them to see if it was full?

Comment: It just shows portraits, at least I don't recall seeing names off the top of my head. If you turn off the feature it would remove the ability to see all that info.

Comment: Might want to mention the ability to hide that info in the answer just in case some googler in the future skips our comments.

Comment: @Rapida - I've edited and included that info.

Answer (score 2):

If you are currently in a game, you can see what character your friend is playing, what quest they are on, and how many people he is partied with, but that is all.

[image]

If you are at the game menu, you can see both the character your friend is playing and *what classes* he is playing with (from the character portraits), as well as the *Act and difficulty* he is playing, but not a specific quest.

[image]

As @Deeyen points out, if your friend has Quick Join disabled, you will not be able to see the party information. The "Party (1/4), 3 open slots" will not show, and you will not be able to see character portraits in the menu screen.

Comment: If quick join is turned off, you can not see how many people are in the game with the person. the "party (1/4), 3 open slots" does not show.